# Text qualifier appears in data when using flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flat-file, ssis-2014

I have a flat file connection manager that reads data from a file that I have constructed with a Powershell script. The fields in the file are delimited with a vertical bar (|) and each field is qualified with the ¬ character (mainly because some fields contain either vertical bar or double quotes).

I have set up my flat file connection manager with the text qualifier specified like so:
[image]

Clicking on preview I can view the data just fine, everything appears to be working.

I then add a flat file source, hook it up to my flat file connection manager, hit the Preview button and that all looks great:
[image]

Yet, when I run the data flow, the text qualifier character (¬) is appearing in each field, like this:
[image]

Can someone please explain to me what is going on here? Because I cannot figure out why this is happening.

---

I tried the suggestions mentioned in the question below with no luck:

- [SSIS Flat File Source Text Qualifier being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938379/ssis-flat-file-source-text-qualifier-being-ignored)

Comment: @Hadi I actually found that question earlier but the suggested answer did not work for me

Comment: I updated the question in order to not been marked as duplicate

Comment: Is it because of Code page Setting?

Comment: @BeiBeiZHU I don't think so. I had 1252 at first, and now I just tried 65001 (UTF-8) because I believe this is what Powershell outputs, but same result unfortunately. I also tried checking the Unicode option, but when doing this it cannot detect the end of the header row and throws an error immediately.